# Schema.org html tags for property website?

Tags: schema.org

I've googled a lot but it seems to be rather difficult to find complete references on the web that is easily digestable,

anyhow,

I've got a fully functioning html5 website that allows people to list their property online and run it in an ebay fashion, although I'd like to optimise my code with schema html tags, from what I gather I can use the schema.org/thing item but I was wondering if there is anything dedicated more to property and also I wanted to ask if anybody managed to get the userinteraction tags working, for stuff like PageLikes etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the property, you could use http://schema.org/SingleFamilyResidence or any other kind of http://schema.org/Residence. Also there are subtypes of http://schema.org/Store if you're allowing those kinds of properties. Really the list is pretty extensive of the types of properties you could have. See http://schema.org/docs/full.html for the entire list of schema.org types.